# disable reading list side panel on mouse move

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

When I am in fullscreen Safari and I move my mouse pointer to the left of the screen, the reading list (?) slides out, and gets in my way.

How do I do one of

- prevent the panel from revealing itself when my mouse is on the left of the screen
- completely disable that panel altogether

Comment: Unfortunately, as of the last operating system, there was no way to prevent that panel or disable that panel. I don't know for certain about the most current OS, but I never read that they changed that in their Change Log, so I'm guessing it's still not possible to disable or prevent it :(

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. Your best bet is exiting full screen mode and resizing safari to fill the whole screen.

Comment: Disable is not possible even on latest Catalina. But to easily resize Safari to fill all the screen hold OPTION while grabbing the corner of the Safari window with the mouse, and it will grow to fill the entire screen as you move the mouse, at once.